# Function in object and access to 'this' property - failed

Tags: javascript, scope

Look at this sample code:

```
var functions = {
 testFunction: function(){
  console.log('testFunction()', this, this.someProperty);
 }      
};
functions.testFunction.someProperty = 'someValue';
functions.testFunction();
```

Why **this.someProperty** in 2nd line is undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj.method()` is syntactic sugar for `obj.method.call(obj)`.

Hence when you do `functions.testFunction()` the `this` reference inside of this function call points to `functions`.

To access it this way you would do:

```
var functions = {
 testFunction: function(){
  console.log(this.testFunction.someProperty); //"someValue"
 }
};
functions.testFunction.someProperty = 'someValue';
functions.testFunction();
```

The `this` keyword is well explained in this [article](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/30/understanding-javascripts-this/).

Answer (score 2):

Because as you could see by a second argument `console.log` outputs - `this` refers to the `functions` object, not to the `testFunction` anonymous function.

This assignment would do what you want:

```
functions.someProperty = 'someValue';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var functions = {
 testFunction: function(){
  console.log('testFunction()', functions, functions.someProperty);
 }      
};
functions.someProperty = 'someValue'; // <------ you should set value to functions's property
functions.testFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:-

```
var functions = {
 testFunction: function(){
  console.log('testFunction()', functions, functions.someProperty);
 }      
};
functions.someProperty = 'someValue';
functions.testFunction();
```